# View full (all) lines in terminal (ubuntu) when using journalctl/systemctl

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

When I try to view something, in many cases I get a message saying `lines X-Y/Y (END)` and those are the only lines printed on my terminal.
Here is an example from `journalctl -xe`:

[image]

I see the same from `systemctl -a` and things like that.
How can I view the remaining text?

Comment: That seems like `less`. Press `h` to get help or read `man less`. Using up/down arrows should work, as should PageUp/PageDown,

Comment: @choroba can you tell me a bit more? what you mean with `less`, as it I've given the example from `journalctl -xe` or `systemctl -a` or like that...

Comment: thanks up-down works! post it as answer, and i'll mark

Comment: The remaining text? You are already seeing the bottom of the text that you are viewing. Please clarify.

Comment: `journalctl` and the other members of the `systemd` family use `less` as the output pager by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your system is using `less` as a pager.

Press <kbd>h</kbd> when running `less` to get help. To learn more, run `man less` from the terminal.

TL;DR: <kbd>PageUp</kbd>, <kbd>PageDown</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd>, and <kbd>↓</kbd> should work in a standard way. <kbd>q</kbd> quits `less`.

Comment: Left and right arrow keys usually work as well (to see the whole lines).

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is an output using `--no-pager`

`journalctl -xe --no-pager`

You can use same by specifying a service also:

`journalctl -u service-name --no-pager`